# blender - scaling object with hair

Tags: modeling

I have a character with hair. Hair with simple children. When I tried scale down the object hair don't changes with an object. But if I change children to none, everything is fixed. If I put interpolated than all hair are mess up.

I tried different variants. I tried parenting everything to null object and scale it down (I read it on one of the forum). Also I tried to disconnect hair, scale the object and connect it again (not worked also). So how to scale the object down with simple children hair?

Comment: Please add screenshots and upload your blend file to help you

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. I made a trick, I converted hair into mesh, mesh into the curve, added some resolution and thickness, and converted back to mesh...